# Does Paypal warn before charging another month of subscription?

Tags: subscription, paypal

I do not have experience with Paypal subscriptions. I have just bought a service which will charge me monthly via Paypal subscription system.

Will Paypal warn me before it charges me the next month? Or this is done silently?

I mean will I get email like "you will be charged in X days for Y service" or I only get email after paypal has paid for another month of the service.

Comment: You have already been warned when you setup the subscription why would you be warned again?

Comment: Surely PayPal's FAQs is the best place to go to for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charge is done silently. The only way you would know you are still being charged is by signing into Paypal or checking your credit card statements.